# echoの出力を、（パイプ？）ファイル出力とクリップボードへ連続出力したい。

Tags: windows, batch-file

(希望）以下の2行目と3行目を、1行にできますか？短くなりますか？

```
chcp 65001
echo %date% %TIME:~0,8% コメント >> txt.txt
echo %date% %TIME:~0,8% コメント | clip
```

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: こんなフリーソフト(ソース付き) [safetee](https://www.vector.co.jp/soft/dos/util/se482246.html) とか、[複数のコマンドを続けて実行する](https://www.adminweb.jp/command/action/index1.html) と [Windows10でクリップボードの内容をコマンドで受け渡しする](https://4thsight.xyz/9317) の組み合わせとかが考えられるでしょう。例えば `echo %date% %TIME:~0,8% コメント | safetee -a txt.txt | clip` とか `echo %date% %TIME:~0,8% コメント | clip & powershell -command "get-clipboard" >>txt.txt` でしょうか。少し違いますが `echo %date% %TIME:~0,8% コメント >> txt.txt & clip < txt.txt` といったことも考えられます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントにUpvoteが付いていて、要望にフィットしているらしいので回答として書き出します。

---

`2行目と3行目を、1行にできますか？短くなりますか？`については[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/26370)で、課題の肝心な部分は、元のやり方では時刻情報の取得が別々に2回行われるので違う時刻が記録される可能性があり、それを回避したいということですね。

以下のような候補が考えられます。

- 環境変数を使う
- PowerShellコマンドを使う
- フリーソフトを使う

その前に、`③任意のコメントを入力したい。`件については、以下の記事が応用できるでしょう。
[【Windows】バッチファイルのコマンドライン引数](https://qiita.com/bokkuri_orz/items/9c9c93fae56cc8653988)
[すべての引数を一括で取得する](https://jj-blues.com/cms/wantto-getallargments/)

`%*`を使えば空白が含まれていても1つの文字列として使えます。

---

**環境変数**

日時情報の取得を1回だけにして、それを作業用の環境変数に格納し、テキストファイルへの追記やクリップボードへの出力は別途行います。
1行にまとめる必要は無く、むしろ行数は増えます。
特に気にする必要は無いのですが、それでも環境変数が増えることを気にするならば、`setlocal`を指定してバッチファイル内だけで使うようにします。

以下のように出来るでしょう。

```
setlocal
chcp 65001
set  logstr=%date%%TIME:~0,8% ランチ開始時刻 %*
echo %logstr% >> txt.txt
echo %logstr% | clip
```

---

**PowerShellコマンド**

質問で使われている`clip.exe`はクリップボードへ書き込むだけのもので、読み出す方法は有りませんが、それがPowerShellコマンドで出来ます。
[Windows10でクリップボードの内容をコマンドで受け渡しする](https://4thsight.xyz/9317)

> 逆にクリップボードの内容（テキストデータ）を取得する場合は、PowerShellの「Get-Clipboard」コマンドレットを利用します。

こんな記事も [クリップボード操作](https://qiita.com/kurukurupapa@github/items/37fc3fe4ec27612ab7df#%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E6%93%8D%E4%BD%9C)

先にクリップボードへ書き込んで、その次にPowerShellコマンドでクリップボードからテキストファイルへ追記します。

```
chcp 65001
echo %date% %TIME:~0,8% ランチ開始時刻 %* | clip
powershell -command "get-clipboard" >>txt.txt
```

こちらも1行にまとめる必要は無いのですが、それでもまとめたいなら`&`で続けて実行します。
[複数のコマンドを続けて実行する](https://www.adminweb.jp/command/action/index1.html)

```
chcp 65001
echo %date% %TIME:~0,8% ランチ開始時刻 %* | clip & powershell -command "get-clipboard" >>txt.txt
```

ただし、上記だと両方とも改行が1つ余分に追加されて空行が出来るようなので、もう少し工夫が必要でしょう。
いっそ全部PowerShellのスクリプトにするのも有りかもしれません。

---

**フリーソフト**

パイプの途中に入れて使えるフリーソフト[safetee](https://www.vector.co.jp/soft/dos/util/se482246.html)というのがあります。

> 標準出力と標準エラー出力を画面とファイルに出力する tee

以下のように出来ます。

```
chcp 65001
echo %date% %TIME:~0,8% ランチ開始時刻 %* | safetee -a txt.txt | clip
```

ソース付きなので、追加したい機能があれば、自分で改造することも出来ます。

---

**その他**

> ②androidでやってみたい。
> ④12時間円グラフ表示したい。

これらは別の手段が必要で、やり方を聞きたいならば別の質問を起こしてください。

ちなみにandroidには標準のスクリプト実行環境は無いと思われますし、そうした環境をインストール・セットアップするのは手間がかかるでしょうから、何か専用のアプリケーションを作った方が良さそうです。

Comment: ②（参考）タイムスタンプhttps://www.amazon.co.jp/m_c8bit-%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%A0%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97/dp/B00VASRBDA/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&qid=1606918720&refinements=p_4%3Am_c8bit&s=mobile-apps&search-type=ss&sr=1-3

Answer (score 3):

２行目と３行目が対等でないことが気になりました。２行目は既存のコンテンツを残したまま追記しています。しかし３行目はそうではなくクリップボードの更新です。`echo`した１行分だけの値になります。
これは本当に望む操作なのでしょうか？

```
chcp 65001
echo %date% %TIME:~0,8% コメント >> txt.txt
ほかにもいろいろ >> txt.txt

clip < txt.txt
```

が望む操作だったりしませんか？

Comment: 無理に「同時」に出すのではなく、オリジナルを作っておいてあとから一括で投げるでいいじゃんという。。賛成です。。。そもそも同時性の要件ってどの程度なのか。。

Answer (score 0):

> クリップボードの更新です。echoした１行分だけの値になります。これは本当に望む操作なのでしょうか？

はい、望む操作です。説明不足で申し訳ありません。

(目的)
時間管理です。
実行時刻の履歴を追加していく。
ついでに、最後の実行結果のみ(1行だけ)をクリップボードへ保存して、すぐにペーストしたい。

(テスト未)
2つコマンドを実行しているので、時間差が発生すると、思います。

(実行例)
実行ファイルを２つ用意する。
1つ目のファイルのコメント：ランチ開始時刻
2つ目のファイルのコメント：ランチ終了時刻

(目標)
①テキスト出力ファイルを使って、ランチタイムの時間集計、平均したい。
②androidでやってみたい。
③任意のコメントを入力したい。
④12時間円グラフ表示したい。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

```
chcp 65001
echo %date% %TIME:~0,8% コメント >> txt.txt & clip < txt.txt
```

上記ソースだと、出力ファイル全部がクリップボードに入ります。
実行結果(出力ファイル)
2020/12/01  9:06:23 コメント
2020/12/01  9:06:30 コメント
実行結果(クリップボード)
2020/12/01  9:06:23 コメント
2020/12/01  9:06:30 コメント
↓
↓
①以下のように、最後の実行結果。最終行の1行だけクリップボードへ保存可能ですか？
実行結果(ファイル)
2020/12/01  9:06:23 コメント
2020/12/01  9:06:30 コメント
実行結果(クリップボード)
2020/12/01  9:06:30 コメント

②他の方法は、まだ試していません。申し訳ございません。

③変数を使う方法しか、ありませんか？

Comment: ここはコメント欄ではありません。回答以外を回答として投稿しないでください。削除すると共に、コメント欄に記述するか、質問文を編集してください。