# DroidScriptで、ボタンEXECUTE_Bしか、表示されません。

Tags: javascript, android

①ボタン2つ。EXECUTE_AとEXECUTE_Bを表示する方法を教えて下さい。
②new Dateを一回に、引数を渡す方法を教えて下さい。
よろしくお願いします。

（参考）【DroidScript】スマホでスマホアプリを作る シリーズまとめ
https://qiita.com/YasumiYasumi/items/832ec009681310ecdd1c

（参考）
[https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/72296/echoの出力を-パイプ-ファイル出力とクリップボードへ連続出力したい/72333#72333](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/72296/echo%E3%81%AE%E5%87%BA%E5%8A%9B%E3%82%92-%E3%83%91%E3%82%A4%E3%83%97-%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E5%87%BA%E5%8A%9B%E3%81%A8%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%B8%E9%80%A3%E7%B6%9A%E5%87%BA%E5%8A%9B%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84/72333#72333)

```
function OnStart() 
{ 
  lay = app.CreateLayout( "linear", "VCenter,FillXY" ); 
  btn = app.CreateButton( "EXECUTE_A", 0.4 ); 
  btn.SetMargins( 0, 0.05, 0, 0 ); 
  btn.SetOnTouch( btn_OnTouch_A ); 
  lay.AddChild( btn ); 
  app.AddLayout( lay ); 

  lay = app.CreateLayout( "linear", "VCenter,FillXY" ); 
  btn = app.CreateButton( "EXECUTE_B", 0.4 ); 
  btn.SetMargins( 0, 0.05, 0, 0 ); 
  btn.SetOnTouch( btn_OnTouch_B ); 
  lay.AddChild( btn ); 
  app.AddLayout( lay ); 

} 
function btn_OnTouch_A() 
{ 
  myDateTime = new Date()
  myDateTime = myDateTime.toLocaleString("ja")
  app.ShowPopup(  myDateTime +" myA" ); 
}
function btn_OnTouch_B() 
{ 
  myDateTime = new Date()
  myDateTime = myDateTime.toLocaleString("ja")
  app.ShowPopup(  myDateTime +" myB" ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

部分回答になりますが、1つ目についてはどちらのボタンも共通の lay, btn に代入してるのが原因だと思います。

`btnA` と `btnB` など区別の付く名前をそれぞれ割り当てるべきです。